# What is Crocodile's secret?

Tags: one-piece

In chapter 540 we can see Ivankov mention Crocodile's weakness. What secret weakness was he referring to?

[image]

Comment: maybe something about his scar?

Comment: Yes, any response would only be speculation.

Like my own.

Croc was a girl, she was turned into a guy by Ivankov.

Comment: Maybe Ivankov and Crocodile were lovers? o.O`

Comment: I like the idea of crocodile beeing luffys mother. It's a bit weird, like so many things in one piece :-)

Comment: @wAy You like how his mother almost killed him several times lol?! Was Crocodile jealous or something and wanted to take revenge for Dragon's actions? Did Dragon dump him for Ivankov or something lol?

Comment: @Peter Raeves When they first met, Crocodile didn't know that Garp was Luffys uncle and after that has been revealed, he helped him (Marineford Arc). Althoug he said, he did it, because he didn't want the Marines to succeed. I don't think, it will be this way, but I do like the idea. Yes. :-)

Comment: @wAy No please no lol. Well maybe you are right after all, who knows. Btw Grap is not Luffy's uncle, but grandfather.

Comment: Maybe Crocodile was kinda like Sanji when he acted like an Okama but then changed quickly realizing he was a man??? Idk

Comment: as it is pure speculation, I would only post a comment... Croco being a woman transformed into a man would be okay, but not embarassing enough, I'd like to go with Croco and Ivan already making out in the past before Croco discovered Ivan was a hormone-fruit user

Answer (score 5):

It was never stated so any response would only be speculation.  With that said, I don't think its the water weakness as Luffy already knows that and wouldn't prompt the reaction Crocodile had.  Most likely knowing Oda its something embarrassing/silly.